# Display all records in third table except for records not found in either of 2 other tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tales Table A, Table B and Table C with the same table structure.
What is the fastest way to display all records in Table C except for records not found in either Table A or Table B

Table A

```
IDNO
------
A100
A200
A300
```

Table B

```
IDNO
------
T555
```

Table C

```
IDNO
-------
A100
A200
A300
T555
X999
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
RECNO
------
A100
A200
A300
T555
```

This is my script, but not sure if it is the fastest one.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TABLEC as a LEFT OUTER JOIN 
TABLEA as a on a.[RECNO] = b.[RECNO] LEFT OUTER JOIN
TABLEB as b on a.[RECNO] = c.[RECNO]
WHERE b.[RECNO] IS NOT NULL Or
c.[RECNO] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: what does `Table C` got to do with your requirement ?

Comment: And how does your expected output match your description?

Comment: @Squirrel, Table is is from the outside csv source which RECNO might not part of Table A and Table B which resides in my database. So I will not include it.

Comment: @TomC, yes it is.

Comment: your requirement is `What is the fastest way to display all records in Table A exept the record not found both in Table A and Table B` . So how `Table C` is not in the picture at all right ?

Comment: In your expected output there is a `T555` but it is not from `Table A`. So where does it comes about ?

Comment: Now that makes more sense.

Comment: @Squirrel , sorry it was a Typo, I already updated it. I have created a code, but I am not sure if this is the fastest way as I have around 1 million records.

Comment: @Squirrel, yes the fastest as I have script added above in the last portion but I am looking for the more fastest because I am handling more than million records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have proper index on RECNO

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM   TABLEC as c
WHERE  NOT
(
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLEA a WHERE a.RECNO = c.RECNO)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLEB b WHERE b.RECNO = c.RECNO)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, I would do this:

```
select * from Tablec
where not exists(select * from tablea where Tablea.idno=TableC.IDNO)
or not exists (select * from tableb where Tableb.idno=TableC.IDNO)
```

Just make sure your have the appropriate indexes.